# Automatic request signing with API Gateway REST API and Amplify

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

This https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/api#signing-request-with-iam says AWS Amplify provides the ability to sign requests automatically ..is this the same with API gateway REST requests that are restricted by Cognito?

```
auth.currentSession().then(token => {
        console.log('>>>>', token.getIdToken().getJwtToken());
        authToken = token.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
        const myInit = { // OPTIONAL
          headers: {
            Authorization: authToken
          },
          response: true,
        };
        api.get(apiName, path, myInit).then(response => {
          // Add your code here
          console.log(response);
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error.response);
        });
      }
    );
```

but I get Authorization header `requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature'`

But in angular this does not work as `Auth.currentSession()` does not compile

```
   endpoints: [
     {
       name: 'test',
       endpoint: 'https://xyz.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test',
       custom_header: async () => {
          // Alternatively, with Cognito User Pools use this:
         return {Authorization: (await Auth.currentSession()).idToken.jwtToken};
       }
     }
   ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved had typo with the request url it had to be `/items/:test` where test was the partition name in dynamo, also the

```
 headers: {
           Authorization: token
         },
```

is **not** required:

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2810#issuecomment-470213459